# Can my C++ program accidentally delete a system file if I delete a pointer?

Tags: c++, windows, pointers, visual-studio-code, dynamic-programming

I am using delete operator quite a lot, in my program. If one of my pointers (say *myPtr*) point to a memory location where a system file is stored.
If I use "*delete myPtr*" in my code, will it delete that file?
My IDE (VS Code) generates an exe file for each program. Is there any difference when I run the program from the integrated terminal, and when I run the exe file.
If the system file is going to be deleted, in which case it will happen - running from ide, running exe file, or both?

Comment: No ned to worry. Pointers point to RAM, not hard disk memory. Also the OS will probably protect those files.

Comment: Nope, to delete the file, you need to make filesystem changes. Load/unloading it into memory should not delete the file.

Comment: If you made a class where the destructor also removed a file, then using the delete operator on such an object of such a class it would attempt to remove the file.  The attempt may fail if the file does not exist, or the user under which the executable is running lacks permissions.  That wouldn't be "accidentally", it would be quite deliberate.

Comment: If the "thing" you're deleting is some object that, as part of its destructor (or those of its base/derivation(s)) delete an on-disk file, then sure, it can happen. But frankly i'd be more concerned with the reason you're using manual memory management in the first place (e.g. *"I am using delete operator quite a lot"*). Smart pointers do nearly all the grunt work for you, and even then only if you really dynamic management (and you'd be surprised how often you *don't*).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any difference when I run the program from the integrated terminal, and when I run the exe file

There shouldn't be any significant difference.

> If one of my pointers (say myPtr) point to a memory location where a system file is stored. If I use "delete myPtr" in my code, will it delete that file?

`delete` frees blocks of RAM. Files are stored on the disk, not in the RAM. Your files are safe.